# Laravel Public Folder Php Artisan

Tags: mysql, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-artisan

Good evening,

I'm currently creating a web application and im using laravel. I have an issue with htaccess I think. If I run the app on a local server and run php artisan serve command, I can use and test the application properly at localhost:8000. However if im not using php artisan serve and try to access the application via the public folder, it works but only for the first page. If I want to send lets say form data when it goes to a url like localhost/content/public/report/savenext it gives me error 404. If I run the same page with php artisan serve at localhost:8000/report/savenext, it works. So how can I configure this properly?

Comment: What laravel version are you using? Also what web server are you using, apache or nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you a rewriteBase defined?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public
```